# istgame package - Action spanning another decision with information set - illegal tree?

Tags: game-theory

I am trying to draw a tree with the `istgame` package, where the branch of the initial node becomes level with the branch of the third node.

However, when I code this as below, I get a node preceded by two other nodes, so an illegal tree.

See the pictures for what I am trying to achieve, and what I am getting currently.

Any help appreciated!

```
\begin{istgame}[font=\scriptsize]
\xtShowArrows %% for arrows
\xtShowEndPoints[ellipse node] %% for arrows
\setistmathTF*001{textsc} % input mode changer
\setistgrowdirection'{east}      % direction

%% tree
\xtdistance{15mm}{20mm} %% determines tree size
\istroot(Owner)<180>{O}
  \istb{H}[al]
  \istb{MD}[a]
  \istb{NH}[bl]
  \endist
 \istroot(OwnerWorker)(Owner-1){}
  \istb{W}[al]
  \istb{S}[bl]
  \endist 
\istroot(Manager)(Owner-2)<90>{M}
  \istb{H}[al]
  \istb{NH}[bl]
  \endist
 \istroot(ManagerWorker)(Manager-1){}
  \istb{W}[al]
  \istb{S}[bl]
  \endist 
 \xtInfoset(OwnerWorker)(ManagerWorker){W}
\end{istgame}
```

[image: What I am trying to achieve]
[image: What I am currently getting]

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I just need to lengthen the arrow:

````
\begin{istgame}[font=\scriptsize]
\xtShowArrows %% for arrows
\xtShowEndPoints[ellipse node] %% for arrows
\setistmathTF*001{textsc} % input mode changer
\setistgrowdirection'{east}      % direction

%% tree
\xtdistance{15mm}{20mm} %% determines tree size
\istroot(Owner)<180>{O}
  \istbA(2.8)<grow=+45>{H}[al]
  \istb{MD}[a]
  \istb{NH}[bl]
  \endist
\istroot(Manager)(Owner-2)<90>{M}
  \istb{H}[al]
  \istb{NH}[bl]
  \endist
\istroot(OwnerWorker)(Owner-1){}
  \istb{w}[al]
  \istbA(1)<grow=-15>{s}[bl]
  \endist  
 \istroot(ManagerWorker)(Manager-1){}
  \istbA(1)<grow=+15>{w}[al]
  \istb{s}[bl]
  \endist 
 \xtInfoset(OwnerWorker)(ManagerWorker){W}[l]
\end{istgame}
```
````